# Always show first row selected in Kendo grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am working on a mvc4 project where I use a Kendo Grid. I want the user to see the first row of the grid selected by default. I have many rows so I use paging. When the user goes to page 2,3,...40 etc i also want to see the first row of each page selected. Below is my code where i create the grid

```
<%: Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
            .Name("AuthorisationsGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
             {
                 columns.Bound(p => p.Mis).Title("MIS").Width(80);
                 columns.Bound(p => p.AuthorisationSerialNumber).Title("ΑΑ Προέγκρισης");
             })
             .Pageable()
             .Sortable()
             .Filterable()
             .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
             .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
             .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Ajax()
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.AuthorisationSerialNumber))
                .Model(model => model.Field(p => p.Mis))
                .Batch(true)
                .Read(read => read.Action("AuthorisationsPartial", "UserFilesDashboard")))%>
```

how can i achieve the above behavior? Maybe jQuery could be useful (but i have very few knowledge of jQuery). Any help appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you can use the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#databound) event of the Grid and jQuery to add the **k-state-selected** class to the first tr element in the tbody of the Grid.

here is an example:

```
$('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.bind('dataBound',function(e){
    this.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected')
})
```

Comment: but this is not really selecting it

Answer (score 3):

Its also possible to do this another way

## Method 1

Bind the grid to the `onDataBound` event via

```
<div data-bind="source: mydataSource, events: {
  dataBound: onDataBound
}" >
```

for MVVM or via the

```
("#gridName").data("kendoGrid").dataBound(..) (not exact)
```

## Method 2

Inside of the

```
databound: function() {
  var uid = data[0].uid;
  var row = roomGrid.table.find('tr[data-uid="' + uid + '"]');
  roomGrid.select(row);
}
```

This works in my case. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.bind('dataBound', function (e) {
            this.select("tr:eq(1)");
            //this.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected');
        })
```

for more detail please see below link
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-select

Comment: Could you explain how this code works? Code-only answers (while accepted at times) could be improved by adding something to explain what it does or how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After updating the code from:

```
$('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.bind('dataBound',function(e){...
```

to:

```
$('#GridName').data("kendoGrid").bind('dataBound', function (e) {...
```

**Now it is fixed and the final code below is working:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#GridMaster').data("kendoGrid").bind('dataBound', function (e) {
        this.element.find('tbody tr:first').addClass('k-state-selected')
    });
});
```

**Note:** If there is a problem for obtaining records on the grid, use this script after the Grid definition instead of before the Grid definition.